# Strange DiracDelta integration results in 10.4.1

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[s (x - c)] x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
          Assumptions -> {s > 0, c > 0}]
```

gives me `c/s` in version 10.3.1, but `1+c+1/s` in version 10.4.1. Have I missed anything here?

Comment: I confirm the result for 10.4.1

Comment: do the assumptions matter? You should only need `s!=0`

Comment: @george2079:  The result would be slightly different (`c/Abs[s]`) for `s < 0`.  But it should still work.  (In fact, both integrals, with `s > 0` and `s < 0`, work fine in 10.2.0.)

Comment: Works fine in version 10.0

Comment: New MMA soft, does not mean better....

Answer (score 8):

Confirmed for 10.4.1 as Alexei. However, WolframAlpha still gives the c/s result.

[See result from Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BDiracDelta%5Bs+(x+-+c)%5D+x,+%7Bx,+-Infinity,+Infinity%7D,+++++++++++Assumptions+-%3E+%7Bs+%3E+0,+c+%3E+0%7D%5D)

And using the properties of Dirac delta function, I would say that c/s is the correct one. May be a bug of the new 10.4.1?

You can test with numeric constants, and Mathematica gives the correct answer. But symbolic result is wrong,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[(x - 3)*2] x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives 3/2.

Another test: it seems it only happens with this expression. This one,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[s ( x - c/s)] x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {s > 0, c > 0}]
```

Gives the correct answer: c/s^2.

**EDIT.- The new Mathematica 11 corrects this issue.**